# How to Make a Grouped Barplot for a Factor with Many Levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, factors

The dataframe **named 'temp'** (below) has three columns (1) Canopy Index; (2) Under_tree; and (3) Open_Canopy. The columns **Under_tree** and **Open_Canopy** are factors with 5 levels each.

```
         data(temp)

            Canopy_index  Under_tree Open_Canopy
          1           75 Undergrowth       Grass
          2           85      Litter       Grass
          3           75      Litter       Grass
          4           35      Litter       Grass
          5           85 Undergrowth       Grass
```

The **dataframe 'temp'** was reformatted to be in long format named **df.melt** (below) to produce a barplot where the **y-axis** is denoted as **Canopy_index** and the **x-axis** represents the factor **Topography (3rd column)** which has **five levels** grouped by **two conditions** (2nd column - Under_Open):(1) Under_tree; and (2) Open_Canopy.

**Problem**

I would like to produce a barplot that looks like **example 1 (below)** with a key for: **(1) Under the Canopy; and (2) Open Canopy**.

In order to produce the barplot, I attempted to used ggplot; however, the results appear to be erroneous because each bar is exactly the same height **(example 2)**. In summary, I am unsure how to fix the error.

If anyone can help, then many thanks in advance.

**Code to convert the dataframe into long format:**

```
   ##response variable = y = Canopy Index
   ##explanatory variables = under and open
   ##Reshape the data to produce one column with under and open

     library(reshape2)
     library(ggplot2)

     under<-factor(temp$Under_tree)
     open<-factor(temp$Open_Canopy)

     data(df.melt)

     df.melt <- melt(temp, id="Canopy_index")

     colnames(df.melt)<-c("Canopy_Index", "Under_Open", "Topography")

             Canopy_Index Under_Open  Topography
           1           75 Under_tree Undergrowth
           2           85 Under_tree      Litter
           3           75 Under_tree      Litter
           4           35 Under_tree      Litter
           5           85 Under_tree Undergrowth
```

**Code for barplot**

```
 ##Grouped barplot showing the topography grouped by under_tree and Open_Canopy

 ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=Topography, y=Canopy_Index,      fill=factor(Under_Open)))+
 geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
 scale_fill_discrete(name="Topographical Feature",
                  breaks=c(1, 2),
                  labels=c("Open_Canopy", "Under_tree"))+
 xlab("Topographical Feature")+ylab("Canopy Index")
```

**EXAMPLE (1):**

[image]

**EXAMPLE (2)**

[image]

**DATAFRAME (temp)**

```
       structure(list(Canopy_index = c(75, 85, 75, 35, 85, 95, 85, 65, 
       75, 95, 75, 95, 85, 75, 85, 95, 75, 85, 85, 85, 75, 75, 85, 85, 
       65, 85, 75, 85, 95, 95, 85, 55, 75, 95, 75, 95, 95, 65, 65, 55, 
       95, 85, 85, 45, 85, 85, 35, 95, 85, 85, 35, 85, 45, 85, 85, 85, 
       95, 85, 85, 75, 85, 35, 85, 85, 65, 65, 85, 45, 55, 95, 75, 95, 
       45, 75, 75, 95, 95, 85, 75, 95, 75, 65, 85, 75, 75, 55, 75, 85, 
       85, 85, 15, 75, 85, 85, 85, 95, 85, 85, 75, 85, 85, 95, 65, 75, 
       95, 55, 75, 85, 85, 85, 95, 55, 85, 75, 75, 85, 85, 85, 85, 55, 
       75, 55, 75, 85, 75, 85, 85, 75, 85, 75, 95, 25, 95, 95, 25, 75, 
       75, 85, 35, 55, 85, 65, 85, 75, 85, 85, 85, 75, 65, 85, 85, 95, 
       65, 55, 95, 95, 85, 95, 85, 65, 55, 65, 55, 95, 75, 85, 85, 35, 
       75, 75, 85, 65, 85, 65, 65, 95, 85, 95, 75, 75, 55, 95, 65, 85, 
       65, 15, 35, 55, 95, 15, 15, 75, 65, 85, 5, 5, 35, 35, 85, 65, 
       45, 35, 65, 65, 75, 65, 15, 75, 65, 45, 25, 65, 85, 45, 85, 75, 
       15, 65, 45, 55, 45, 15, 45, 75, 65, 75, 65, 35, 95, 65, 35, 35, 
       65, 45, 75, 35, 75, 85, 35, 55, 65, 85, 65, 65, 85, 55, 15, 75, 
       65, 45, 45, 85, 55, 15, 85, 15, 95, 75, 5, 55, 15, 35, 45, 85, 
       65, 65, 65, 65, 25, 85, 35, 55, 65, 75, 5, 45, 65, 15, 75, 55, 
       65, 55, 35, 75, 65, 65, 85, 35, 65, 55, 75, 15, 55, 65, 75, 55, 
       85, 35, 55, 55, 25, 75, 15, 55, 75, 75, 65, 55, 45, 75, 25, 45, 
       95, 55, 75, 45, 25, 35, 55, 15, 15, 75, 35, 55, 55, 65, 45, 65, 
       25, 55, 45, 65, 65, 25, 25, 65, 45, 95, 55, 25, 55, 85, 45, 85, 
       15, 75, 65, 35, 75, 15, 55, 85, 35, 55, 45, 85, 45, 65, 55, 75, 
       65, 85), Under_tree = structure(c(6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
       6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
       4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
       4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
       4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
       4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
       6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
       6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
       4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
       4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
       5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
       4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
       4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
       5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
       5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
       5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
       6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
       4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("", "Artificial_Surface", "Bare_soil", 
       "Grass", "Litter", "Undergrowth"), class = "factor"),      Open_Canopy = structure(c(4L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
       2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
       4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
       4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
       4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
       4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
       6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
       6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
       4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
       2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("",      "Artificial_Surface", 
       "Bare_soil", "Grass", "Litter", "Undergrowth"), class =    "factor")), .Names = c("Canopy_index", 
        "Under_tree", "Open_Canopy"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
        6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
       19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
       32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
       45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
       58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 
       71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 
       84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
       97L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 
      109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
      120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 
      131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 
      142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 
      153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 
      164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
      175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
      186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 
      197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
      208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 
      219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 
      230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 
      241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 
      252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 
      263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 
      274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 
      285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 
      296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 
      307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 
      318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 
      329L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 
      340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 
      351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 
      362L, 363L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The problem is in the data, you have multiple values per category and plots all the bars on top of each other, leaving only the highest one visible. You can see this is happening if you add `colour = "white"` to your geom_bar.

Comment: Thank you Marjin, your advice was insightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to plot means of `Canopy_Index` for each `Under_Open`, `Topography` cell, you can form means first:

```
df.means <- aggregate(Canopy_Index ~ Under_Open + Topography, df.melt, mean)
```

Then, plot `df.means` using the code from your question:

```
ggplot(df.means, aes(x=Topography, y=Canopy_Index, fill=Under_Open)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Canopy Type",
         labels=c("Under_tree"="Under Canopy", "Open_Canopy"="Open Canopy")) +
  xlab("Topographical Feature") + ylab("Canopy Index")
```

Result:

[image: Plot output]

The reason why the bars are currently almost all of the same height is that you overlay multiple values per cell ([as pointed out in the comments by Marijn Stevering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549596/how-to-make-a-grouped-barplot-for-a-factor-with-many-levels/41550321#comment70304499_41549596)), effectively plotting the max:

```
df.max <- aggregate(Canopy_Index ~ Under_Open + Topography, df.melt, max)
# Under_Open         Topography Canopy_Index
# 1   Under_tree Artificial_Surface           75
# 2  Open_Canopy Artificial_Surface           95
# 3   Under_tree          Bare_soil           95
# 4  Open_Canopy          Bare_soil           95
# 5   Under_tree              Grass           95
# 6  Open_Canopy              Grass           95
# 7   Under_tree             Litter           95
# 8  Open_Canopy             Litter           95
# 9   Under_tree        Undergrowth           95
# 10 Open_Canopy        Undergrowth           95
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice Thales, it was deeply appreciated. I am attempting to put a legend on the barplot. Would you have any idea how to insert a legend with a title called Canopy Type in conjunction to being labelled Under Canopy and Open Canopy. I am grateful for any further suggestions. Take care

Comment: @AliceHobbs, I corrected your code (the `breaks=c(1, 2)` did not make sense) to give the desired labels.