# ggplot2: Add legend and associated legend title to barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

I have the following barplot which was produced from [the data-set 'temp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549596/how-to-make-a-grouped-barplot-for-a-factor-with-many-levels/41550321#41550321) (the data is situated at the bottom of this stack overflow page and can also be found by following this link above).

[image]

**PROBLEM**

The objective is to add a legend to the right hand side of the barplot (above) titled as **Canopy Type** with labels denoting **Under Canopy** and **Open Canopy**.

I tried using scale_colour_manual as given in another stackoverflow answer but I can't get a legend to show up.

If anyone can help, then many thanks in advance

**The code to generate the barplot was:**

Assuming you want to plot means of Canopy_Index for each Under_Open, Topography cell, you can form means first:

```
 df.means <- aggregate(Canopy_Index ~ Under_Open + Topography, df.melt, mean)
```

Then, plot df.means using the code from your question:

```
  ggplot(df.means, aes(x = Topography, y = Canopy_Index, 
                     fill = factor(Under_Open), group = Under_Open)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Topographical Feature", 
                      breaks = c("Under_tree", "Open_Canopy"),
                      labels = c("Under Canopy", "Open Canopy")) +
  xlab("Topographical Feature") + ylab("Canopy Index") +
  scale_colour_manual("Canopy Type", values = c("red", "blue")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
        text = element_text(size=14)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.line.x =     element_line(color="black", size = 0.8),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.8))
```

Comment: Running that code on my machine has the legend showing up named as "Topographical Feature"

Comment: Using your code I do get a legend, which is produced by scale_fill_discrete. scale_colour_manual can't produce a legend since there is no colour argument in the aes.

Comment: That's odd! After running the code, the legend fails to appear. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: Restart R and try again, maybe make sure your packages are up to date.

Comment: Hi Gregor, thank you for your suggestion. The problem was the code itself, and the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to 'Thales' for providing the code to resolve this problem

**Code to produce the barplot with associated legend:**

```
     ggplot(df.means, aes(x=Topography, y=Canopy_Index,fill=Under_Open)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
     scale_fill_discrete(name="Canopy Type",
                breaks=c("Under_tree", "Open_Canopy"),
                labels=c("Under Canopy", "Open Canopy")) +
     xlab("Topographical Feature") + ylab("Canopy Index")
```

**Barplot**

[image]